# Can I get a Datetime object from a unix timestamp?

Tags: programming, time

Is there a way to get a DateTime object from a unix timestamp and hour offset? I want to be able to print a formatted string, for example `Wed Apr 02 17:15:06 2014`.

I have:

1. A unix timestamp: `1396451852`.
2. An offset from my hour zone, `+1` hour.

Note: I get the timestamp from an internet service and want to make the conversion in the Arduino.

Comment: To clarify: You have a unix time-stamp on your arduino and you want to make the conversion there? Could the supplier of the timestamp instead provide the formatted string?

Comment: Yes! i get this unix time-stamp from internet.

Answer (score 2):

The seconds since (UNIX) epoch relies on a [database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database).

> New editions of the database and code are published as changes warrant, usually several times per year.

Your options can:

- Reduce the timezone database to the timezone you are actually interested in;
- Don't forget about daylight savings time for you specific timezone;
- The leap years are well known too and reasonably easy to program;
- The leap seconds are decided upon usually only couple months before they are introduced and therefore cannot be accounted for in an algorithm.

### Conclusion

- So can you convert epoch to a time/date format? Yes.
- Will it be accurate? It'll drift away over time (months or years)

### Advise

If you retrieve epoch from an Internet service, why not use (another?) webserver that has the full timezone database available to convert it to accurate date/time, or 'synchronize' against every once in a while?

Comment: +1 For letting me know that *leap seconds* exist AND for the great answer.

Answer (score 1):

The [Arduino Time Library](http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/Time) looks like it can do it. Or have a look at the strftime() function from unix and unix-oid environments. There is [source to strftime() here](http://www.jbox.dk/sanos/source/lib/strftime.c.html). It's pretty large but you can probably cut it down considerably to just the format parts you need.